# rpivotTable in shiny - hide rendererName dropdown list

Tags: r, shiny, rpivottable

I am trying to hide the renderer dropdown list within shiny app.

I have tried the method listed here ([Hide the filters in Shiny DT datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119372/hide-the-filters-in-shiny-dt-datatable)) by adding `tags$style` but it doesn't seem to work.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  tags$style(type = 'text/css', "#pivot tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)  {display:none; }"),

    rpivotTableOutput('pivot')
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)

function(input, output, session) {

  output$pivot <- renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(iris)
  })

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, just need the following line:

**server.R**

```
tags$style(type = 'text/css', ".pvtRenderer {visibility: hidden}")
```